# How does one start patenting an idea in India?

Tags: patentability, software, law, mobile, india

I have an invention to do with Mobile cloud services. I'm not versed on the subject but I am technically inclined (I study computer engineering). How would I go about obtaining a patent for my invention?

Answer (score 2):

Obtaining a patent is a first step to compete with commercial competitors. According to the The Patent Act, 1970. The following are not inventions according to section 3(k) of Indian Patent Act, 1970

"a mathematical or business method or a computer programme per se or algorithms"

Not all the inventions are fall under this category hence some of the software inventions are patentable in India.

According to "[Manual of patent office practice and procedure](http://ipindia.gov.in/ipr/patent/manual/HTML%20AND%20PDF/Manual%20of%20Patent%20Office%20Practice%20and%20Procedure%20-%20pdf/Manual%20of%20Patent%20Office%20Practice%20and%20Procedure.pdf)" it is mention that which type of softwares are eligible for patent and which type of softwares are eligible for copyright.
Just check it in detail:

http://ipindia.nic.in/IPActs_Rules/updated_Version/sections/ps3.html

Answer (score 1):

The Indian Patent Office has a eFiling system. Check the folowing link.

[Intelectual Property India](https://ipindiaservices.gov.in)

[User Guide](http://ipindiaservices.gov.in/epatentfiling/UsefullDownloads/Comprehensive%20efiling%20manual)

Comment: hi https://ipindiaservices.gov.in/ePatentFiling/UserRegistration/NewUser is not allowing to register.any idea ?

Comment: you require digital certificate to do filing.. You should do physical filing